# Creating a loop in HTML to auto load pictures from a directory

Tags: javascript, html, directory

I know there are similar questions to these but I couldn't figure out how to word it short enough to do a search so I will just try here.

Basically I have a website I'm designing and we are wanting to do a rotating banner on the website. I have found code where people have designed the banners but it seems to be that with every one I find the code enforces you to hardcode the image itself into the HTML or Java Script depending on what their doing. So my question is this:

Is there a way for me to be able to loop through the contents of the folder and whenever it gets a name, display the name for "x" amount of time and then pull the next picture?

I could do this in my sleep with Java or C# but I get confused when it comes to stuff like this is JS and HTML..

Thank you for the help..

Here is the current image loading code i'm looking at with Java Script.

```
var ImageLoad = 
[
['index.htm',   'graphics/one.jpg',     'Blue Flower'           ],
['index.htm',   'graphics/two.jpg',     'Distant Rainstorm'     ],
['index.htm',   'graphics/three.jpg',   'Raindrops on a Leaf'           ],              
['index.htm',   'graphics/four.jpg',    'Jungle Dream'          ],
['index.htm',   'graphics/five.jpg',    'Daisies'           ],
['index.htm',   'graphics/six.jpg',     'Sunflowers'            ]
];
```

Comment: It's possible, but it's easier to just create a webservice that returns all of the URL's to the images from a specific folder. That way you can do it in `C#`..in your sleep `;-)`

Comment: Okay I think I see where your going with this. now my next question would be where do I go next in order to create this webservice to return all of those URL's. Like what language do I need to research in order to be able to accomplish this. Because the main focus of my knowledge resides in HTML or CSS when it comes to web design.

Comment: Try with WCF (Windows Communication Foundation), Or you could just create Action that return JSON object with list of the urls (if within ASP MVC). What is your choice of server-side technology?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the time I didn't have many resources. Now I would say that the best option would be to create a rest call that can pull all the files located in a folder needed and then return them in a json format and loop through them.

I never implemented this but I will give credit to the 2 post that went on there.

Thank you for your help!